# "than would be"

Tags: grammar

1. I was wondering if "... than would
   be ..." is <del>Irrealis</del> subjunctive mood?
2. What is neglected between "than" and
   "would", given that "than" is conj.?

For example:

> Programs are larger, more complex, or
>   have a greater span than would be
>   practical within a single project.
>
> The weather here is warmer than would
>   be expected at <del>that</del> this latitude because
>   of the influence of surface currents.

Comment: I'm having trouble understand the question here. The two examples are correct in form. Can you please rephrase your question?

Comment: I understand the text and examples, but do not know what to answer. The _than would_ could be replaced by _than a single project would make practical_ --- _than that latitude would make you expect_

Comment: What is an "irrealis mood"?

Comment: @kiamlaluno, [Irrealis mood](http://tinyurl.com/3su7nvn)

Comment: Voting to close. I do not believe that Wikipedia article on *Irrealis moods* has any significant credibility.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: *realis and irrealis moods* are discussed in other sources than Wikipedia, including [Semantics by John I. Saeed](http://goo.gl/2vO72) and  [The prominence of tense, aspect, and mood by D. N. Shankara Bhat](http://books.google.com/books?id=cTNFyNZXkTcC) (among others). [A Dictionary of Grammatical Terms in Linguistics](http://books.google.com/books?id=erHbSh1xGvgC) also contains a definition, though it notes that at least one source recommends against its use -- however, it is an actual term. I don't see why this should be closed, per se.

Comment: @rintaun: Thanks! Could you give some sources for saying`at least one source recommends against its use `? What would they call this grammatical phenomenon then?  I believe this concept is widely used by mainstream linguistists.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I beg to differ. I don't believe this concept is not widely used in English grammar. Disclaimer: I am not native English speaker, but all the English grammar books I have read when I was learning English in school emphasized irrealis mood.

Comment: @Tim: The text of the entry from the dictionary I cited is available at [this website](http://www.bookrags.com/tandf/irrealis-tf/); I have not read the referenced paper so I cannot give any more specific information. However, the term *irrealis mood(s)* is **not** used widely in English grammar, which may be related to the fact that very few of the *irrealis moods* exist in English (I believe only the conditional and subjunctive moods do). Out of curiosity, and if I may ask: what is your native language?

Comment: @Tim: If you are interested, the referenced book is apparently: Palmer, F. R. 1986. *Mood and modality.* Cambridge, England: Cambridge University.

Comment: @rintaun, @Tim: Well I hope I can always stand to be corrected. The whole area seems to be dominated by *Indian* linguists, who had little international academic standing 40 years ago when I wasn't paying that much attention to my studies anyway. It would be interesting to hear from UK/US-based practicing academics on the matter.

Comment: ...the site is still at the "commitment" stage, but a proposal for *linguistics.se* has been around for some time now. I suggest anyone who strongly approves of this type of question should go there and commit, so it can move on to the "beta" phase... http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics

Comment: @FumbleFingers I agree wholeheartedly with your comment about committing to *[linguistics.se](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/6673/linguistics)*. There are actually US-based academics weighing in on the matter (or so say my -- admittedly cursory -- searches through LLBA), but really, mood and modality are essentially black magic to me. :) I do agree that this question would be better suited to *linguistics.se*, however.

Comment: @rintaun: I learned English in China. I admit that I was lost in translation when posting the question. The English grammar books there call the grammatical phenomenon as `虚拟语气`, which should be `subjunctive mood` instead of `irrealis mood`.

Comment: @rintaun It was easier to say "a mood that is not the [indicative mood](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=indicative+mood)".

Comment: @kiamlaluno There's quite a bit more to it than that; there are several other *realis* moods than simply *indicative*.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand it, "Irrealis mood" is not a mood in and of itself, but rather a set of grammatical moods, which, according to Wikipedia "indicate that a certain situation or action is not known to have happened as the speaker is talking." I believe that your examples above of "than would be" **may be examples of the conditional<sup>1</sup> mood** (one of the irrealis moods), but I admit a lower level of expertise in the subject of moods than I likely should have.

Nothing is being *neglected*, as these are both grammatical English sentences, but if one were to rewrite these sentences without ellipsis, one might rewrite them as the following:

> 1. Programs are larger, more complex, or have a greater span than [it] would be practical [to contain] within a single project.
> 2. The weather here is warmer than [the weather] would be expected [to be] at that<sup>2</sup> latitude because of the influence of surface currents.

Obviously, as a sentence with much simpler structure (i.e. a shorter subject), the second sentence is easier to rewrite in this manner.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup> My original answer posited subjunctive, but upon further inspection, I believe it to be the conditional mood.</sub>
<sub><sup>2</sup> Incidentally, I would also change change  *that* to *this* -- because we are not speaking of *there*, but rather *here*. **Note:** This was written prior to the question being updated.</sub>

Comment: that=this - my thoughts too when commenting. What do you make of my comment by the way?

Comment: @mplungjan: From a semantic viewpoint, it conveys the same information, but I felt as if @Tim wanted something which was *deleted*, rather than simply rephrasing the second half of each sentence.

Comment: @rintaun: Thanks for pointing the `that` problem. I replaced it with `this`.

Comment: I still feel the clause after `than` are subjunctive, because they state something not real as the clause before `than` is the reality. AFAIK, the usage `would` is often used to express subjunctive mood.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly an answer. Firstly the various *irrealis* modes aren't particularly relevant to this site, because most of them don't even exist in English. They're to do with comparative linguistics, and they're primarily of interest to comparative linguistics because collectively, many languages can convey a vast range of nuances relating to ability, preference, permission, obligation, likelihood, etc. In the normal context of parsing English, OP's examples are simply in the *conditional* mode.

Turning to those examples, I have to say I simply don't understand the first one. In my understanding, a *project* may comprise multiple *programs*; I don't see how a program can be more complex than the containing project itself.

The second example is ambiguous. It could be saying the weather is simply warmer because of the surface currents. Or it could be saying it's *even warmer* than would be expected given the latitude and currents, without specifying a reason.

Comment: Comments on your comments to the examples: (1) For the first one, on the contrary to `a project may comprise multiple programs`, a program is about several related projects (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_management). (2) For the second one, I can't see from the last paragraph the differences between the original sentence and your suggested two alternative ways.

Comment: @Tim: (1) I don't think much of that Wikipedia page - nor do others who have flagged it as poor quality. Apart from anything else, it confuses a management program with the management of programs. It lists a set of "projects" called *design, modifications, marketing*, and *training*, so we're not exactly talking about standard nomenclature here.

Comment: (2) The sentence can be interpreted either of two ways as I've set out. Do you not see both interpretations?